# Send and receive 868Mhz radio signals

Tags: hardware, wireless, radio

In my home I have sun-shade that I can control via a handheld transmitter. I already figured out that it is sending on 868 mhz.

Now I'd like my raspberry to read send those signal instead (or as well as) the handheld remote.

The main problem I am currently facing is that I find quite a lot of tutorials on how to do that with 433 mhz modules and a ton of hardware modules.

For 868 mhz I just can't find a tutorial nor the hardware that I need. My 433 modules were super cheap thingies... Aren't there the same ones for 868 mhz.

I live in Austria (Europe) so something available in Europe would be nice :) 
Any hints are very very welcome!!!!

Comment: [This Enocean board](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-69367/l/868mhz-radio-frequency-module-for-raspberry-pi) looks like it might do the job, although it's relatively expensive for what sounds like a fairly dumb radio transmitter. What might be useful is that it looks quite well documented.

Comment: Hm... it also takes up quite a few GPIOs on my raspberry :(
Would be great if I could find something like http://www.amazon.de/Aukru-Superregeneration-433M-receiver-module/dp/B00R2U8OEU/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1457102592&sr=8-1&keywords=433+mhz but only for 868 mhz :)

Comment: http://www.amazon.de/NRF905%C2%A0433-915MHz-Wireless-Modul-Arduino-funktioniert-offiziellen/dp/B0161LGR6W/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1457102651&sr=8-1&keywords=868mhz ?

Comment: sending from china... will take a couple of weeks to arrive :) and I want to hack :)

Comment: One from GB [here](http://www.ebay.de/itm/NRF905-Tri-band-Transceiver-433-868-915-MHz-Wireless-Module-D01-/221378237549?hash=item338b2bd46d:g:ICAAAOxyn9BRccMI).

Comment: I think if they write GB they mean China :) Shipping would take about 2-3 weeks... :( I am currently searching on ebay... maybe I'll find something there

Comment: I'm trying to do the same. Note that nRF905 may not be useful for your shades, as the link layer protocol is part of the chip and uses GPSK modulation and a fixed frame format. I have an nRF905 and I could not use it with any of my 868MHz widgets. Please comment if you find something ;). Also check: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38283/what-kind-of-modulation-is-this .

Comment: @Georg Do you mind giving an update? I am also in the same situation, and although I see a few 868MHz RF transmitters our there, they either would use up all my GPIOs, or don't convince me they could talk to my (elero-brand) blinds…

Comment: @Dave I ended up using Homematic receivers. So didn't continue investigating the whole thing. Sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to look at is the [IEEE_802.15.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.15.4) standard specification. That include many popular protocols for the frequency you are interested in, such as: 
[ZigBee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee), `ISA100.11a, WirelessHART, MiWi, SNAP`, and `Thread`.

That frequency belong to the Unlicensed ISM/SRD bands: `863.0 – 870.0` **MHz** (ETSI EN 300 220). So there are tons of devices Arduino, RPi etc devices that you can use to transmit.

Also check [LoRa](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/wiki/LoRaWAN/Home) devices.