# Control 868MHz device from a RPi4

Tags: pi-4, home-automation, radio

I am trying to control my electric blind (*elero* brand, controlled by [this remote](https://www.elero.com/en/downloads-service/downloads/?tx_avelero_downloads%5Bdownload%5D=320&tx_avelero_downloads%5Baction%5D=download&cHash=2b5c961f89e27370f8023983cceef0c1)) from my RPi4, and while I'm fine tinkering with anything on the software side, I must admit my knowledge of GPIO and RF stuff is close to nil.

Much like [this previous poster](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43561/send-and-receive-868mhz-radio-signals), I've found out that 868MHz RF transmitters are a lot less common than 435MHz. And of the ones leftover, I struggle to confirm which ones might let me capture and replicate the signals sent by my remote…

Among (local) online options, I found:

- [LoRa RF transmitters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GPLJTWD) ostensibly geared at Arduino (but I guess could be wired to the RPi4 GPIO ports?), but also specific to LoRa protocol, which doesn't seem to be what my blinds use (?)
- [Waveshare LoRa hat](https://www.waveshare.com/sx1262-868m-lora-hat.htm) which would take up all my RPi4 GPIO ports… Also: still LoRa…
- Various boards and USB gateways to the "enocean" protocol, which I'm assuming also wouldn't play with my random other-brand blinds…

Any guidance on what type of RF transmitter I should be looking for, and what the next steps might be to hook it up to my RPi4 and replicate existing signals?

Comment: The Pi is pretty tangential to any answer.  You first of all need to find the protocol used to communicate with the blinds.  There isn't a single radio protocol.

Comment: use software defined radio module and a computer ... start with an SDR stick such as this one ... many tutorials are on the web ... https://www.adafruit.com/product/1497

Comment: There are loads of cheapie 868MHz transceivers from AliExpress:
https://www.aliexpress.com/popular/868mhz-transceiver.html. I would recommend RFM95. I used to play with RFM12 433MHz in my Arduino Decimilla days. One catch is tha you need to learn SPI which has a steep learning curve.  But they are tons of SPI tutorials out there. Or modify Arduino RFM12 C++ sketches.

Comment: This is the cheapie US$5 Rpi4B buster compatible SPI 868MHz transceiver I recommend: https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32811523237.html?spm=a2g0w.search0302.3.2.865c4e54pSvF5J&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=6299f20a-1e75-4a79-81d8-b24e494d952a&algo_expid=6299f20a-1e75-4a79-81d8-b24e494d952a-0.  In case you are using Rpi4B buster Python 3.7.3 Thonny 3.2, I will be glad to try to help out debugging.

Comment: Or try this RpiZero bonnet for 868MHz RFM95 Lora compatible module : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MV7OzW8YHas.

Comment: More references (WARNING: Very expensive!): (1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnHwWGqUUyc,
(2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MV7OzW8YHas.

Comment: And as usual, Lady Ada has newbie friendly tutorials on RFM95 868MHz and also Lora stuff: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-rfm69hcw-and-rfm96-rfm95-rfm98-lora-packet-padio-breakouts,

Comment: @tlfong01 Thanks for all the recommendations, but from my (limited) understanding of the other comments, chances are high that the (likely-proprietary) protocol used by my blinds would not be compatible with LoRa… Correct?

Comment: @joan Indeed, the first stepe (figuring out what RF protocol I even need) seems only tangentially-related… I guess I was hoping there was a solution that would let me detect, then use, the protocol with a single piece of hardware…

Comment: @jsotola thanks for pointing me in that direction… If I understand correctly, the path forward would be: 1. get SDR receiver 2. scan and somehow identify protocol used by remote on 868MHz band 3. program an SDR transmitter to send the same messages…?

Comment: i think that the SDR module is only a receiver ... use it to receive the signal from the remote control ... if the received data changes with every button press, then the data is encrypted in some way, and it may not be possible to emulate the remote control

Comment: Hi @Dave, Ah, let me see.  I am sorry that I think I misunderstood your comments.  So far what I am pretty sure is that your remote is RF 868MHz.  You did mention that you don't want Lora, but not sure for any reason, perhaps because you need to pay licence fee. So I recommend the cheapie RFM95 which is 868MHz and also Lora compatible. I am not very sure what you want is a remote for the curtain or blind.  If yes, you can let us know the link to the blind, so we can work out from there.